# How to notify web client of Azure storage or servicebus queue events

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-storage-queues

I am using Azure storage and/or servicebus queues. Messages are queued and dequeued via the python sdk.

I also have a web application, that is showing a list of the items in the queue. Currently, the user has to manually refresh the web app so the list of queue items shows the correct content.

What I would like to do is some notify the web client so it can refresh automatically. I couldn't find an obvious way to do it.

What is the recommended best practice to notify a web client of queue changes with Azure? Something like a callback via WebSocket would be nice.

I noticed that Azure functions can be triggered when a new item is added to the queue. However, this function seems to actually consume the item. Also the function doesn't get triggered when some other process dequeues an item.

Comment: Which kind of azure function you use?

Comment: "type": "queueTrigger", "direction": "in"

Answer (score 0):

My guess is maybe you should try with [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-azure-functions)

[Here](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Using-the-Azure-SignalR-Service-Bindings-in-Azure-Functions-to-Create-Real-time-Serverless-Applications) you can find an example of one concrete implementation. The difference is that the function is Http Triggered, but is applicable to other function triggers as well..

Comment: Thank you @kgalic. So far I haven't found a way to trigger the function of queue events other than message added event.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more your current setup? what means 'message added event' ? :)  Can you push the message directly to the event hub for example in parallel with pushing the message to the storage queue, as you have more than 1 consumer for the storage queue?

Comment: The binding of the function to storage queue event seems to have only one possible value for "direction", which is "in". Based on the behaviors I am seeing, this seems to mean that the function is triggered when a message is added to the queue. When messages are dequeued, i.e. peek, get, delete, the function is not triggered. For our use case, we would want the function to trigger on any change to the queue.